# How can i return the login page after signing up new user using firebase and react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Iam building an App with a signup and login feature but can't get to the login page after signing up.
I have tried to use react navigation as below

```
handleSignUp = () => {
        firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            .then(function() {
                // Sign-out successful.
                this.props.navigation.navigate("logn")

              })
            // .then(signout=>{

            // })
            .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }));
    };
```

This leads me to the home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register screen movement below member registration section.

```js
handleSignUp = async () => {
   const result = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
          this.setState({ errorMessage: 'The password is too weak.' })
        } else {
          this.setState({ errorMessage: errorMessage })
        }
      });

  if (result) {
     this.props.navigation.navigate("logn")
  }
}
```